# Sapper Rollup proxy config for Netlify functions

Tags: javascript, proxy, netlify, rollup, sapper

I'm using the [Sapper Rollup template](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template-rollup) and can't figure out how to proxy `/.netlify/functions` to `localhost:9000`. I've tried `http-proxy-middleware` in a setupProxy.js file but I'm not sure where to reference that file given the Sapper dev server doesn't seem to be configurable with Rollup?

I have a function in `/src/functions/get-code.js` and I'm using Netlify lambda to test it:

`package.json`

```
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "sapper dev",
  "lambda:dev": "netlify-lambda serve src/functions",
  ...
```

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  functions = "lambda"
```

I can test my function on `https://localhost:9000/get-code` and it's working fine. However, in my app I have a function inside a file `utilities.js` which is trying to make a request to `/.netlify/functions/get-code.`

```
export const getCode = (obj) => {
  return axios
    .post('.netlify/functions/get-code', JSON.stringify(obj))
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return null
    })
}
```

When I run my app (`npm run dev`) and this function is called, it results in an `ECONNREFUSED` error because it's trying to call `http:.netlify/functions/get-code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing in an Eleventy project, until I realized I didn't have to. Instead of using netlify-lambda and trying to proxy to port 9000, just use [Netlify Dev](https://www.netlify.com/products/dev/) instead.

Install the Netlify CLI:

```
npm install netlify-cli -g
```

then run Netlify Dev from your project folder:

```
netlify dev
```

It'll start your app and handle your http requests to `/.netlify/functions/get-code`, so you can avoid the proxy problem, as well as CORS issues.